# delete child node in xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

i'm trying to remove a child node from an xml.
 my script is working..but it removing a few childs... and not just the one i want to remove...

can you look and tell me what is my problem?

**The XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<events>
   <record>
      <id>3</id> 
   </record>
   <record>
      <id>2</id> 
   </record>
   <record>
      <id>1</id> 
   </record>
 </events>
```

**The delete.php file:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
);
$users = new DOMDocument();
$users->load("xmp.xml");

$suser = simplexml_load_file("xmp.xml");
$count = 0;
$user = $users->getElementsByTagName("record");

foreach($user as $value)
{
   $tasks = $value->getElementsByTagName("id");
   $task  = $tasks->item(0)->nodeValue;

   if ($task == $record["id"]) {
    $users->documentElement->removeChild($users->documentElement->childNodes->item($count));
   }
   $count++;
}

$users->save("xmp.xml");

?>
```

Comment: why is this line in the code: `$suser = simplexml_load_file("xmp.xml");`?

Comment: Hmm.. i have no idea.. it's mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the node you want to remove. Call `removeChild()` on it's `parentNode`, e.g.

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

On a sidenote, you can do this with less code when using XPath:

```
$id  = /* some integer value */ 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('file.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = sprintf('/events/record[./id = "%d"]', $id);
foreach($xpath->query($query) as $record) {
    $record->parentNode->removeChild($record);
}
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

will remove the `<record>` element with an `<id>` child node having the value stored in `$id`.

[Run code on Codepad](http://codepad.org/ppvwDAsA).

More examples: [remove element from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317854/remove-element-from-xml)

Comment: can you be more detailed? Where should i put this line in my script?

Comment: @Ofear instead of your `removeChild` call.

Comment: This is great! Works perfect!! can you please add in the first line $id = "some integer number" ;  for others who will look for answer? Thanks you very much gordon!