# how i can delete child node from XML file

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i have this XML :

```
 <photo>
 <position>1</position>
 <title>panos1</title>
 </photo>


 <photo>
 <position>2</position>
 <title>panos2</title>
 </photo>

 <photo>
 <position>3</position>
 <title>panos3</title>
 </photo>

 <photo>
 <position>4</position>
 <title>panos4</title>
 </photo>
```

i want to delete the  `position`  tag with value `4` using PHP.

I'm using `Xpath`

Comment: You want to delete JUST the `photo` child element `position` or you want to delete the corresponding parent `photo` element entirely?

Comment: Googling `how i can delete child node from XML file php` shows some promising results

Comment: Refer to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667433/delete-child-node-in-xml-file-with-php

Comment: Panos Kar, Xpath is a query language for XML documents and as such it cannot alter (delete or insert nodes in) an XML document. XSLT is a language that is especially designed for performing XML transformations. Your problem has a trivial solution using XSLT. Would you like to see an XSLT solution in your answers?

Comment: Dimitre show me if you want..

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeChild(). 
Look at this:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->loadXML($str) or die("Error");

// original
echo "<xmp>OLD:\n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

// get document element
$root   = $xml->documentElement;
$fnode  = $root->firstChild;

//get a node
$ori    = $fnode->childNodes->item(1);

// remove
$fnode->removeChild($ori);

echo "<xmp>NEW:\n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
?>
```